# Sql get Employee Working hour weekly as per start day of week(e.g start day of week,monday,tuesday ,etc)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have this table that i used to save user login logout detail. 
I want to query data with start day of week,  and fetch  data weekly,
e.g if i query  from march 1 2016 to march 28 2016 and my start day of week is Wednesday  then i need  all employee data weekly 
march 2 to 8
march 9 to 15
march 16 to 22 
for each employee . If anybody work more then 40 hour in that week then i need to calculate extra hour also.

```
CREATE TABLE #tempWeekdatbefore 
(EmployeeId BIGINT, LoginTime DATETIME, LogOutTime DATETIME)


INSERT INTO #tempWeekdatbefore (EmployeeId,LoginTime,LogOutTime)
Values
(83     ,'2016-03-09 06:55:22.000', '2016-03-09 14:29:11.000'),
(98     ,'2016-03-09 07:04:22.000', '2016-03-09 11:53:12.000'),
(84     ,'2016-03-09 07:07:06.000', '2016-03-09 13:39:03.000'),
(136    ,'2016-03-09 07:29:14.000', '2016-03-09 13:20:24.000'),
(420    ,'2016-03-09 07:33:48.000', '2016-03-09 11:42:52.000'),
(101102 ,'2016-03-09 07:49:25.000', '2016-03-09 11:42:53.000'),
(425    ,'2016-03-09 07:49:45.000', '2016-03-09 12:47:46.000'),
(100750 ,'2016-03-09 07:56:26.000', '2016-03-09 12:43:16.000'),
(90     ,'2016-03-09 08:03:51.000', '2016-03-09 11:19:38.000'),
(78     ,'2016-03-09 08:52:09.000', '2016-03-09 13:26:56.000'),
(89     ,'2016-03-09 09:06:57.000', '2016-03-09 13:41:30.000'),
(60600  ,'2016-03-09 09:31:17.000', '2016-03-09 17:13:48.000'),
(219    ,'2016-03-09 11:50:51.000', '2016-03-09 15:07:42.000'),
(90     ,'2016-03-09 11:54:38.000', '2016-03-09 16:47:30.000'),
(420    ,'2016-03-09 12:12:33.000', '2016-03-09 14:53:59.000'),
(101102 ,'2016-03-09 12:12:42.000', '2016-03-09 16:43:33.000'),
(337    ,'2016-03-09 12:17:22.000', '2016-03-09 15:54:39.000'),
(98     ,'2016-03-09 12:22:27.000', '2016-03-09 16:39:59.000'),
(425    ,'2016-03-09 13:08:09.000', '2016-03-09 17:00:16.000'),
(100750 ,'2016-03-09 13:09:32.000', '2016-03-09 15:00:00.000'),
(136    ,'2016-03-09 13:32:12.000', '2016-03-09 16:00:00.000'),
(84     ,'2016-03-09 13:50:37.000', '2016-03-09 16:23:04.000'),
(89     ,'2016-03-09 14:11:00.000', '2016-03-09 15:00:00.000'),
(101147 ,'2016-03-09 14:52:07.000', '2016-03-09 19:03:44.000'),
(81     ,'2016-03-09 14:54:05.000', '2016-03-09 19:08:47.000'),
(219    ,'2016-03-09 15:31:52.000', '2016-03-09 19:08:48.000'),
(100701 ,'2016-03-09 16:00:18.000', '2016-03-09 19:05:08.000'),
(337    ,'2016-03-09 16:27:44.000', '2016-03-09 19:08:50.000'),
(90     ,'2016-03-09 16:54:34.000', '2016-03-09 17:38:00.000')

SELECT EmployeeId
,SUM(CASE WHEN ISNULL(RegTime, 0)>40 THEN RegTime-40 ELSE 0 END) AS ExtraHour
,SUM(CASE WHEN ISNULL(RegTime, 0)>40 THEN 40 ELSE RegTime  END) AS RegTime
FROM(

Select EmployeeId,
     DATEPART(dw,LoginTime) AS WeekNumber,
     DATEPART(MONTH,LoginTime) AS MonthNumber,
     DATEPART(Year,LoginTime) AS YearNumber,
     SUM(CONVERT(decimal(18, 2), 
     DATEDIFF(MINUTE, LoginTime, isnull( LogOutTime,getdate())) / 60.00)) AS RegTime
FROM        #tempWeekdatbefore WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE      (convert(date, LoginTime) >= convert(date, '3/9/2016')) AND 
( convert(date,LogOutTime) <= convert(date, '3/9/2016'))
GROUP BY EmployeeId, DATEPART(dw,LoginTime), 
DATEPART(MONTH,LoginTime), DATEPART(Year,LoginTime)) as e 
GROUP BY EmployeeId, WeekNumber, MonthNumber, YearNumber
```

Comment: What is the issue you're facing?

Comment: issue with grouping data weekly as per start day of week .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some work on determining the first day and last days of previous, current and next week with a variable starting day of week when building a BusinessObjects universe ([First day of previous week with a twist](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-52212)).

Clearly, the BusinessObjects portion doesn't apply, but I still think the underlying SQL may still be helpful...

```
declare @StartDate datetime
declare @StartDateDayOfWeek int
declare @BeginningDayOfWeek int

set @StartDate = '03/01/2016'
set @StartDateDayOfWeek = DATEPART(dw, @StartDate)

set @BeginningDayOfWeek = 4 --Wednesday

select DATEADD(DAY, (-7 + ((@StartDateDayOfWeek - @BeginningDayOfWeek + 7) % 7)) * -1, @StartDate)
, DATEADD(DAY, (-13 + ((@StartDateDayOfWeek - @BeginningDayOfWeek + 7) % 7)) * -1, @StartDate)
, DATEADD(DAY, (-14 + ((@StartDateDayOfWeek - @BeginningDayOfWeek + 7) % 7)) * -1, @StartDate)
, DATEADD(DAY, (-20 + ((@StartDateDayOfWeek - @BeginningDayOfWeek + 7) % 7)) * -1, @StartDate)
, DATEADD(DAY, (-21 + ((@StartDateDayOfWeek - @BeginningDayOfWeek + 7) % 7)) * -1, @StartDate)
, DATEADD(DAY, (-27 + ((@StartDateDayOfWeek - @BeginningDayOfWeek + 7) % 7)) * -1, @StartDate)
```

If copy that SQL and run it you will get the dates you mentioned. You will clearly need to adapt this to your situation, but hopefully that will get you going in the right direction.

Noel